Can any SPI device be daisy chained?
I have an application where I need to read from a 2 m long chain of 20 or so IMUs. Space is a concern, so I would ideally find a way to put them all on a single bus in a way that minimizes wire count. I think SPI daisy chaining could be a good method, but I have minimal experience in this area. Can any SPI device be daisy chained, or does the datasheet have to explicitly mention support for daisy chaining?
SPI daisy chaining is my top approach as it minimizes ICs and wire count, but I am also considering shift registering by adding a microcontroller next to each IMU, I2C with address translators next to each IMU, SPI with demultiplexer for to minimize chip select lines, and I3C.

Welcome to [electronics.se]! I've edited your question to one question. We require one question per question post, and the other question was a shopping question anyway (shopping questions are off-topic).

What kind of data rates are you expecting? Could you provide what IMU you are looking to use?

SPI with a one of N counters for chip enable  (CD4017 etc)

Can any SPI device be daisy chained?
No.
Generally it would mean that a chip would clock out bits sent to it. Not all chips will do that. Even if some or all chips did do that, they would send out something, so the first chip would get correct data in, but also the first chip and the rest of them would send incorrect data out to next chips.
It will only work with certain chips, such as shift registers that only pass out data clocked into them and don't care what is clocked in until the data is latched in.
Any register based chip like an IMU will assume first it is sent a register address to access, and if that access is read or write. So they can't be chained.
